# how to update row items in sqlite table using android?

Tags: android, sqlite

I am developing an app i want to update record with new values with old values but when i am trying to update it also shows old values again. I have string array in row item and i want to update this string array with new values in my app, I.e i have to show old values with new values in app. But in my code i show update but its repeated the old values? How do i solve this? i have navigate within activities doing this operation.

example : i have string array like

```
str1[] str1= {"1","2","3","4"};
str2[] str2= {"a", "b","c","d"};
```

now i have to update this with new values like

```
str1[] str1= {"1","2","3","4","6", "8"};
str2[] str2= {"a", "b","c","d", "j", "l"};
```

and my output shows in current code is

```
str1[] str1= {"6", "8","1","2","3","4","1","2","3","4"};
str2[] str2= {"j", "l","a", "b","c","d", "a", "b","c","d"};
```

code

```
// list values

    private void checkButtonClick() {

        ArrayList<String> list1= new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<String> list2= new ArrayList<>();

        Poses country = null;
        ArrayList<Poses> countryList = dataAdapter.countryList;
        for (int i = 0; i < countryList.size(); i++) {
            country = countryList.get(i);
            if (country.isSelected()) {
                // responseText.append("\n" + country.getName());
                list1.add(country.getName());
                list1.add(convertArrayToString(subject));
                list2.add(country.getCode());
                list2.add(convertArrayToString(spinner));
            }
        }
        final String [] names = list1.toArray(new String[list1.size()]);
        final String [] spinner = list2.toArray(new String[list2.size()]);

        dbManager.update(id1, names, spinner);
    }

//db values query

 public int update(long _id, String [] selected_pgm, String [] spinner_value) {
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(DatabaseHelper.SELECTED, convertArrayToString(selected_pgm));
        contentValues.put(DatabaseHelper.SPINNER, convertArrayToString(spinner_value));
        int i = database.update(DatabaseHelper.TABLE_NAME, contentValues, DatabaseHelper._ID + " = " + _id, null);
        return i;
    }
```

Comment: before add items to list, clear them first. `list1.clear()` and `list2.clear()`

Comment: @JohnJoe I am trying to do but it clears all records of list

Answer (score -1):

You Can Directly use rawQuery method to update.
Refer :

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html

example-

```
String updateQuery ="UPDATE myTable SET xyz = 1 WHERE id_abc = " + jkl+"";
Cursor c= dbManager.RawQuery(updateQuery, null);
c.moveToFirst();
c.close();
```

Comment: Answer edited. It will not be a good practice if I will write code for you.
Refer my solution, you will get the solution for sure.